# How to make a movie clip play only if two symbols are visible?

Tags: function, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a movie clip (symbol1) that I only want it to play if two other symbols are visible at the same time (symbol2 and symbol3)... Something like this, but instead of making the symbol visible, I want to play it:

```
function do_magic():void
{
    symbol1.visible = symbol2.visible && symbol3.visible;
}
```

Thanks a lot,

Tom

Comment: Question is too broad.

Comment: Sorry, I will explain it better @DodgerThud

Comment: Don't ever do it at home: **symbol1[(symbol2.visible && symbol3.visible)? "play": "stop"]();**

Comment: Please, [start at the very basics of programming](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/conditionals.html).

Comment: Thank you both for your help! The problem is officialy solved :)